# Can you use the bimah as a shortcut?

Tags: halacha, synagogue

I read [online](http://havolim.blogspot.com/2009/02/terumah-mishkan-and-beis-haknesses.html) that one cannot take a shortcut from one area of the shul to another if it cuts through the area of the bimah. The pertinent line is:

> Just as the Mizbeiach was elevated, our Bimah, too, is elevated. The elevation is not just for better acoustics or line of sight, it is minhag Yisrael, to the extent that one is prohibited from taking a shortcut from one side of the shul to the other by way of the Bimah platform, because the platform is considered a different, and more holy, reshus.

Is this actually the case and if so what is the source for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eliezer Eisenberg here, author of that post.  The source is the Mekor Chaim, written by the author of the better known Chavos Yair, Rav Yair Bachrach, in Orach Chaim 151:5.  I generally included citations, but I wanted to avoid that sort of thing in that particular post.

Comment: Hi Eliezer, thank you for following up! I look forward to seeing you around.